# Which is the best practice to access config inside a function?

Tags: php, config

```
<?php
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__)); //Absolute path to index

/*
* Method 1
* Dependency Injection
*/
class Config{

    private $_config = NULL;
    private $_filepath = NULL;

    public function __construct($filepath){
        $this->_filepath = $filepath;
        $this->load();
    }

    private function load(){
        if ($this->_config === NULL){
            if (!file_exists($this->_filepath)){
                throw new Exception('Configuration file not found');
            }else{
                $this->_config = parse_ini_file($this->_filepath);
            }
        }
    }

    public function get($key){
        if ($this->_config === NULL){
            throw new Exception('Configuration file is not loaded');
        }
        if (isset($this->_config[$key])){
            return $this->_config[$key];
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Variable ' . $key . ' does not exist in configuration file');
        }
    }
}

function getLost($where, $why, $who){
    //do smth
}

try{
    $config = new Config(ABSPATH . '/app/config.ini');
    getLost('here', 'because', $config->get('who'));    
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
/*
* Method 2
* Config is accessed via static class
*/

class Config{

    private static $_config = NULL;
    private static $_filepath = NULL;

    public static function load($filepath){
        if (self::$_config === NULL){
            self::$_filepath = $filepath;
            if (!file_exists(self::$_filepath)){
                throw new Exception('Configuration file not found');
            }else{
                self::$_config = parse_ini_file(self::$_filepath);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function get($key){
        if (self::$_config !== NULL){
            throw new Exception('Configuration file is not loaded');
        }
        if (isset(self::$_config[$key])){
            return self::$_config[$key];
        }else{
            throw new Exception('Variable ' . $key . ' does not exist in configuration file');
        }
    }
}

function getLost($where, $why){
    $who = Config::get('who');
}

try{
    Config::load(ABSPATH . '/app/config.ini');
    getLost('here', 'because');    
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
/**
* Method 3
* Config variable needed is passed as function parameter
*/
$config = parse_ini_file(ABSPATH . '/app/config.ini');

function getLost($where, $why, $who){
    //do smth
}

getLost('here', 'because', $config['who']);
?>
```

---

```
<?php
/*
* Mathod 4
* Config is accessed inside a function via global
*/
$config = parse_ini_file(ABSPATH . '/app/config.ini');

function getLost($where, $why){
    global $config;
    $who = $config['who'];
}

getLost('here', 'because');
?>
```

Which of these variants is the best practice solution? If none, please provide your variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for variant 1 (dependency injection).

Variant 2 uses `static` methods which are as already stated just enother way of `global` methods. And we all know that is bad right? right?

Variant 3 isn't me favorite because it's not OOP enough ;-), but serious: what if you (or the person using your code) wants to change the format of the config file?

Variant 4: `global`...

So basically my issues with other options are: testability, tight coupling, global.

So variant 1 it is. I would also create an interface for the config class so you may add a different class for your config stuff at a later point. E.g. you (or someone else for that matter) wants to use XML files for config.

Another thing I would change is `private` stuff. If someone wants to extend the class he/she wouldn't have access to the variables this way. My rule of thumb (not sure if everybody agrees with this though) is only make stuff `private` if you want people to have access to it (e.g. it will change at some point). The danger of using `private` is that people will get around it by hacks to do what they want.

Read more about [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and see the Google [clean code](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=google+clean+code+talks&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CG8QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.g-truc.net%2Fpost-0182.html&ei=9JkFUIKjFsjVtAbc1qCkBg&usg=AFQjCNFm7v0EzstqyZfhumeFaCpxlUCeYw) talks for more info.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree with the blanket statement that one should immediately do away with `private`. Not all algorithms should automatically be subject to modification by child classes. Composition is generally preferable to inheritance. Judicious `protected` usage can go a long way to keeping the black box "black." That said, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say first case is better if you replace $config with $onlyTheStuffThatMattersToThatFunction

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but I have to +1 because you're so right and this is the only sensible answer at this point :)